Using moved{} block to change: "count block-> for_each block" in Terraform for azure resources
Using moved{} block to change: "count -> for_each" in Terraform script for azure resources, so that the resources won't be recreated when the count variable is updated
Terraform version: ">=1.1.7"
Problem Statement: moved block not supported.
I have this existing code


I have tried the following solution


but getting this error:
Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on asp.tf line 34:
│   34: moved {
│
│ Blocks of type "moved" are not expected here.


main.tf


Which terraform version are you using?

Please post the code as text, not pictures.

@ShamraiAleksander - Please don't edit questions to embed screenshots of code; How to review edits that add images? suggests not to do this.

Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as text rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? for why. For instructions on formatting see How do I format my code blocks?. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Here is a working example using plain resources.  Not sure about your error, looks like you have a syntax issue.  Be sure to specify the exact resource with a [0] appended and the target with the ["key"]
Before:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
      version = "2.5.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "local" {
  # Configuration options
}

locals {
    enable_feature = true
    features = [
        "feature1",
        "feature2"
    ]
}

resource "local_file" "foo" {
    count = local.enable_feature == true ? 1 : 0
    content  = "foo!"
    filename = "${path.module}/foo.bar"
}

Apply the Before:
terraform apply

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # local_file.foo[0] will be created
  + resource "local_file" "foo" {
      + content              = "foo!"
      + content_base64sha256 = (known after apply)
      + content_base64sha512 = (known after apply)
      + content_md5          = (known after apply)
      + content_sha1         = (known after apply)
      + content_sha256       = (known after apply)
      + content_sha512       = (known after apply)
      + directory_permission = "0777"
      + file_permission      = "0777"
      + filename             = "./foo.bar"
      + id                   = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

local_file.foo[0]: Creating...
local_file.foo[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=4bf3e335199107182c6f7638efaad377acc7f452]
…ec/projects/testing/move [✔] [3.24s]
PS  cat ./foo.bar                             
foo!

After the move:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
      version = "2.5.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "local" {
  # Configuration options
}

locals {
    enable_feature = true
    features = [
        "feature1",
        "feature2"
    ]
}

# resource "local_file" "foo" {
#     count = local.enable_feature == true ? 1 : 0
#     content  = "foo!"
#     filename = "${path.module}/foo.bar"
# }

resource "local_file" "foo" {
    for_each = local.enable_feature == true ? toset(local.features) : []
    content  = "foo!${each.key}"
    filename = "${path.module}/foo.bar.${each.key}"
}

moved {
  from = local_file.foo[0]
  to = local_file.foo["feature1"]
}

Apply the move:
terraform apply
local_file.foo["feature1"]: Refreshing state... [id=4bf3e335199107182c6f7638efaad377acc7f452]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # local_file.foo["feature1"] must be replaced
  # (moved from local_file.foo[0])
-/+ resource "local_file" "foo" {
      ~ content              = "foo!" -> "foo!feature1" # forces replacement
      ~ content_base64sha256 = "wOCqrqBQvPO+JsDCPVj6iQwN+3nIojAWtKhs0oym6nE=" -> (known after apply)
      ~ content_base64sha512 = "TSCmPxazw2YStHurNILfRykjK/J4evgArH/2KnQuzQZodz4cq1f/ig2GeQO7mBI+Qx5jkTQEZxLCGs3mPtsB3Q==" -> (known after apply)
      ~ content_md5          = "35af8b7a9490467f75f19c1e5459f7e7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ content_sha1         = "4bf3e335199107182c6f7638efaad377acc7f452" -> (known after apply)
      ~ content_sha256       = "c0e0aaaea050bcf3be26c0c23d58fa890c0dfb79c8a23016b4a86cd28ca6ea71" -> (known after apply)
      ~ content_sha512       = "4d20a63f16b3c36612b47bab3482df4729232bf2787af800ac7ff62a742ecd0668773e1cab57ff8a0d867903bb98123e431e639134046712c21acde63edb01dd" -> (known after apply)
      ~ filename             = "./foo.bar" -> "./foo.bar.feature1" # forces replacement
      ~ id                   = "4bf3e335199107182c6f7638efaad377acc7f452" -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # local_file.foo["feature2"] will be created
  + resource "local_file" "foo" {
      + content              = "foo!feature2"
      + content_base64sha256 = (known after apply)
      + content_base64sha512 = (known after apply)
      + content_md5          = (known after apply)
      + content_sha1         = (known after apply)
      + content_sha256       = (known after apply)
      + content_sha512       = (known after apply)
      + directory_permission = "0777"
      + file_permission      = "0777"
      + filename             = "./foo.bar.feature2"
      + id                   = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

local_file.foo["feature1"]: Destroying... [id=4bf3e335199107182c6f7638efaad377acc7f452]
local_file.foo["feature1"]: Destruction complete after 0s
local_file.foo["feature2"]: Creating...
local_file.foo["feature2"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=666f26a4c3808e86eaf50642f9776898b8e93131]
local_file.foo["feature1"]: Creating...
local_file.foo["feature1"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=9045433ccd83efc4451ba48e4a8a4d45965e8324]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.
…ec/projects/testing/move [✔] [9.45s]
PS  cat ./foo.bar.feature1
foo!feature1
…ec/projects/testing/move [✔] [60.08ms]
PS  cat ./foo.bar.feature2
foo!feature2

You can see with this simple example how you need to target the resources by exact name based on the state.
